# What is the meaning of this line in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$line =~ s/^<(\w+)=\"(.*?)\">//;
```

What is the meaning of this line in perl?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger

Comment: It's a [regex substitution](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html). It removes text like `<abc="d1">` at the start of a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @LukStorms, this is more for comment than for direct duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s/.../.../` is the substitution operator. It matches its first operand, which is a regular expression and replaces it with its second operand.

By default, the substitution operator works on a string stored in `$_`. But your code uses the binding operator (`=~`) to make it work on `$line` instead.

The two operands to the substitution operator are the bits delimited by the `/` characters (there are more advanced versions of these delimiters, but we'll ignore them for now). So the first operand is `^<(\w+)=\"(.*?)\">` and the second operand is an empty string (because there is nothing between the second and third `/` characters).

So your code says:

- Examine the variable `$line`
- Look for a section of the string which matches `^<(\w+)=\"(.*?)\">`
- Replace that part of the string with an empty string

All that is left now is for us to untangle the regular expression and see what that matchs.

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `<` - matches a literal `<` character
- `(...)` - means capture this bit of the match and store it in `$1`
- `\w+` - matches one or more "word characters" (where a word character is a letter, a digit or an underscore)
- `=` - matches a literal `=` character
- `\"` - matches a literal `"` character (the `\` is unnecessary here)
- `(...)` - means capture this bit of the match and store it in `$2`
- `.*?` - matches zero or more instances of any character
- `\"` - matches a literal `"` character (once again, the `\` is unnecessary here)
- `>` - matches a literal `>`

So, all in all, this looks like a slightly broken attempt to match XML or HTML. It matches tags of the form `<foo="bar">` (which isn't valid XML or HTML) and replaces them with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It's searching for an XML tag at the start of a string, and substituting it with nothing (i.e. removing it).

For example, in the input:

```
<hello="world">example
```

The regex will match `<hello="world">`, and substitute it with nothing - so the final result is just:

```
example
```

In general, this is [something that you shouldn't do with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610). There are a dozen different ways you could create false negatives here, that don't get stripped from the string.

But if this is a "quick and dirty" script, where you don't need to worry about all possible edge cases, then it may be OK to use.

Comment: That's not valid XML, so doubt many of the XML parsers would accept it.

Comment: Agreed -- but I presume that this line of code is part of a larger "XML sanitisation" script. I bet there's a bunch more substitution commands, to strip "other formats" of tags.